# Does Google App Engine have any support for cookieless domains?

Tags: google-app-engine

It seems like static files can only be served from the same domain as the app.

I could create a new app for hosting static files but I'm a little nervous that that would a violation of the [terms of service](http://code.google.com/appengine/terms.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to serve your static content from a different app, you just need to use a different hostname. App Engine makes it pretty easy to have many different hostnames that point to the same app.

With wildcard subdomains you don't even have to create a DNS entry. If your app lives at `myapp.appspot.com`, you can also reach it through any subdomain, like `static.myapp.appspot.com`. If you're using your own domain, you'll need to [configure it manually](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/domain.html).

Comment: Just to clarify, the procedure Drew is describing works for custom domains, too: www.myapp.com and static.myapp.com can be configured to point to the same app

Answer (score 1):

"4.4. You may not develop multiple Applications to simulate or act as a single Application or otherwise access the Service in a manner intended to avoid incurring fees"

"You may not develop" but, you can "Enable Billing" for multiple application. An example:

1) mysite.appspot.com
2) mysite-static.appspot.com
3) mysite-data-service.appspot.com

Answer (score 0):

Section 4.4 of the [terms of service](http://code.google.com/appengine/terms.html) prohibit one from splitting one logical app into two pieces - so hosting your dynamic content and static content in two separate GAE apps would violate the terms.

However, you could host static files on another web hosting service - anything from a simple shared hosting solution all the way up to a big CDN.  This approach enables your site to serve static content from domains other than your app's domain.